# performing calculations on arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question on how to perform calculations on arrays. I used the length of the array that is in the calculation as the length of the array that stores the calculations. In my case, all my calculations on arrays works fine except for one; it displays this when I execute my program:

```
run:
Planets:              Mercury               Venus               Earth                Mars             Jupiter              Saturn              Uranus             Neptune               Pluto
Radius:               2439.70             6051.90             6378.00             3402.50            71492.00            60270.00            25562.00            24774.00             1195.00
Mass:                3.30e+23            4.87e+24            5.97e+24            6.42e+23            1.90e+27            5.68e+26            8.68e+25            1.02e+26            1.31e+22
Gravity:                 3.70                8.87                9.79                   3.70               24.78               10.44                8.86               11.13                0.61


3.7
8.87
9.79
3.7
24.78
10.44
8.86
11.13
0.61
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
at GravityV1.main(GravityV1.java:118)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class GravityV1
{
// calcGravity returns an array of doubles containing teh gravity values
//and takes two arrays of doubles as parameters for the radius values and mass
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
{
    // fill in code here
        double[] grav = new double[radius.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++){
            grav[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
        }
        return grav;
    // The formula to calculate gravity is:
    // 6.67E-17 times the massOfPlanet divided by the radius of the planet squared
}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    // Initialize variables
    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
    double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23),
                1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 *
                    Math.pow(10,22)};
// // calculate my weight on each planet

            // declare & initialize my weight variable
            double myWeight = 123.0;

            // array for storage
            double[] weight = new double[gravities.length];

            // for loop
            for(i = 0; i < gravities.length; i++){
                weight[i] = myWeight * gravities[i];
            }
            System.out.println(weight[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 for(i = 0; i < gravities.length; i++){
       weight[i] = myWeight * gravities[i];
 }
 System.out.println(weight[i]);
```

to

```
 for(i = 0; i < gravities.length; i++){
       weight[i] = myWeight * gravities[i];
       System.out.println(weight[i]);
 }
```

Comment: @user2967353: In general, when writing a `for` loop on an index variable it is **much** better to declare the variable inside the `for` statement: `for (int i = 0; i < ...)`, and get rid of the `int i` declaration outside the loop (I don't even see where it's declared).  The compiler would have caught your error early if you had done this.  It's relatively rare that you would need to initialize your index before the loop or use the last value of the index after the loop.

Comment: @user2967353: P.S. you did this right in `calcGravity`.  So maybe doing it wrong in `main` was just a typo.